# WCH Link Failed to configure MCU

Tags: microcontroller

I just got a CH32V003 dev board with a WCH-LinkE-R0-1v2 and I am unable to make it work. It seems to have something to do with the WCH-LinkE-R0-1v2 firmware.

When I try to re-update the firmware with the WCH-Link Utility, I get:
22:16:21:440>> Begin to set chip type...
22:16:21:496>> Failed,the chip type is not matched or status of chip is wrong!

When I go back to Moun River and try to "Download" my project to the CH32V003 with my WCH-Link, I get:
------------ Begin flash process of "obj\GPIO_Toggle.hex" ------------
22:01:44:297 >> Current project vendor is WCH, debugger is WCH-Link

```
22:01:44:297 >> Attempt to open link device and upgrade firmware if necessary...
22:01:44:394 >> Link Device is CH32V305. Already the latest version v2.8, no need to upgrade

22:01:44:473 >> Starting to Handle Operations...
22:01:44:536 >> Failed to configure mcu.
Failed to configure mcu. Please refer to "WCH-LinkUserManual.pdf" for more help.

22:01:44:536 >> Starting to Close Link...
22:01:44:536 >> Close Link Success
```

---------------------------------End ---------------------------------

When I open Moun River and go to "Flash/Configuration" and try any of the top button, I get:
0000#22:20:53:985>> Failed to configure mcu.

Does anyone know how I could make this work?

At first, I installed and opened Moun River Studio Community and I opened the GPIO example for the CH32V003 from the WCH github.
Then I tried flashing my chip and I was prompted with a message like "Wch Link firmware out of date, do you want to update?" I clicked on yes and All lights on the WCH-Link turned off and it seemed to stop working. I searched the WCH website and documentation and found the WCH-Link Utility. I Opened the FIRMWARE_CH32V305.bin because the chip on my WCH-Link is a CH32V305. I took a few tries to Update the firmware "successfully". Now the red LED is always on and I am unable to do anything with  the WCH-Link.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change to RISC-V Mode, when programmer both diodes are on, this means that it is working in ARM Mode.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to get the WCH Link-E there are more than one version of WCH Link. MounRiver will update the firmware for you. The link will still not work, MounRiver has a utity section you need to select Risc v mode and data pass through (click on unlock) which will enable you to program the ch32v003 EVT board. D0-D17 -- PA_1 PA-2 PC_0 PC-7 PD-0 PD-7.
Best,
PeterG

Answer (score 0):

I was able to repair it using the following method described on page 16 of the manual.

1. Open the plastic case and take out the board. (The case is just fitted, not glued.)
2. With WCH-LinkUtility running, connect to the PC while holding down the IAP button.
3. When the blue LED is blinking, a confirmation dialog for the update will be displayed, so click OK to update.
4. Once the update is completed successfully, you will be able to use it again.
5. If that doesn't work, you need to write "WCH-LinkE-APP-IAP.bin" using cheap WCH-Link.